# Image location is not loaded while using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I am trying to show the image location using PHP. The JS code below works for me.
When I try to echo the JS code below it stops working.
`$dbid` is the id of the car. I am able to import the car image which corresponds to the id of the car.

**1) JS code**

```
var CarImage = document.createElement('img');
CarImage.setAttribute('src', '<?php echo importCarImageLocation($dbid);?>');
document.body.appendChild(CarImage);
```

Result: The code works and the image is found and loaded.

**2) Trying to echo the js code.**

```
echo
"var CarImage = document.createElement('img');
CarImage.setAttribute('src', '<?php echo importCarImageLocation($dbid);?>');
document.body.appendChild(CarImage);";
```

Result:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbid in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test3.php on line 9
```

**3) Using php solution of creating the elements and setting the attributes and echoing the image location**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$test = $dom->createElement("img");
$testattribute = $dom->createAttribute("src");
$testattribute->value = "<?php echo '/images/cars/1.jpg' ?>" ;
$test->appendChild($testattribute);
$dom->appendChild($test);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result: The element and the attributed are created, but the image location is not found. The browser is showing a
    broken image, which probably indicates that it cannot find the image.

**4) Using my function of getting the image location as the source**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$test = $dom->createElement("img");
$testattribute = $dom->createAttribute("src");
$testattribute->value = "<?php echo importCarImageLocation($dbid);>" ;
$test->appendChild($testattribute);
$dom->appendChild($test);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result: `Notice: Undefined variable: dbid in C:\xampp\htdocs\basel\testing\test3.php on line 12`

**5) Not echoing nor using my function of getting the image location**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$test = $dom->createElement("img");
$testattribute = $dom->createAttribute("src");
$testattribute->value = "images/cars/1.jpg" ;
$test->appendChild($testattribute);
$dom->appendChild($test);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result: The image is found and loaded

Can you tell me why number 2, 3 and 4 do not work.

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove PHP tag from these lines from all `$testattribute->value = "<?php echo '/images/cars/1.jpg' ?>" ;` `$testattribute->value = "<?php echo importCarImageLocation($dbid);>" ;`